# error when converting pixel manipulation from processig to p5.js

Tags: processing, p5.js

I have been trying to convert a simple contrast and red channel manipulation sketch to p5.js.

The original .pde works well using processing.js:

```java
// Declaring a variable of type PImage
PImage img;

void setup() {
  size(564, 698);
  // Make a new instance of a PImage by loading an image file
  img = loadImage("../image.jpg");
}

void draw() {
  loadPixels();

  // We must also call loadPixels() on the PImage since we are going to read its pixels.  img.loadPixels();
  for (int x = 0; x < img.width; x++ ) {
    for (int y = 0; y < img.height; y++ ) {

      // Calculate the 1D pixel location
      int loc = x + y*img.width;

      // Get the R,G,B values from image
      float r = red (img.pixels[loc]);
      float g = green (img.pixels[loc]);
      float b = blue (img.pixels[loc]);

      // We calculate a multiplier ranging from 0.0 to 8.0 based on mouseX position.
      // That multiplier changes the RGB value of each pixel.     
      float adjustBrightness = ((float) mouseX / width) * 4.0;
      float adjustRed =  ((float) mouseY / height) * 2.0;
      r *= adjustBrightness;  // see https://processing.org/reference/multiplyassign.html
      g *= adjustBrightness;
      b *= adjustBrightness;

      r *= adjustRed;

      // The RGB values are constrained between 0 and 255 before being set as a new color.     
      r = constrain(r,0,255);
      g = constrain(g,0,255);
      b = constrain(b,0,255);

      // Make a new color and set pixel in the window
      color c = color(r,g,b);
      pixels[loc] = c;
    }
  }

  updatePixels(); 

}
```

However, when converted to p5.js the updated script (below) returns an error:

```java
Error: Needs p5.Color or pixel array as argument.
```

I've left some comments in for things I've tried:
    var img;
    // var sensitivity;

```java
function preload() {
  img = loadImage("../image.jpg");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(564, 698);
  pixelDensity(1);
  img.loadPixels();
  loadPixels();
}

function draw() {
  loadPixels();
  for (var x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < img.height; y++ ) {
      // Calculate the 1D location from a 2D grid
      var loc = (x + y*img.width)*4;
      // Get the R,G,B values from image
      var r,g,b;
      r = red (img.pixels[loc]);
      g = green (img.pixels[loc]);
      b = blue (img.pixels[loc]);
      // Calculate an amount to change brightness based on proximity to the mouse
    //   var maxdist = 50;
    //   var d = dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY);

      var adjustBrightness = (mouseX/width)*4;
      var adjustRed = (mouseY/height)*4;
      r *= adjustBrightness;
      g *= adjustBrightness; 
      b *= adjustBrightness;

      r *= adjustRed;
      // Constrain RGB to make sure they are within 0-255 color range
      r = constrain(r, 0, 255);
      g = constrain(g, 0, 255);
      b = constrain(b, 0, 255);
      // Make a new color and set pixel in the window
      //color c = color(r, g, b);
    //   var pixloc = (y*width + x)*4;
    c = color(r,g,b);
    pixels[loc] = c;
    //   pixels[loc] = r; //red
    //   pixels[loc+1] = 40; //green
    //   pixels[loc+2] = b; //blue
    //   pixels[loc+3] = 50; //alpha
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

I think the problem may be in the red() green() blue() functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin, who got things on the right track, here's the working p5.js script:

```
function preload() {
  img = loadImage("../image.jpg");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(564, 698);
  pixelDensity(1);
  img.loadPixels();
  loadPixels();
}

function draw() {
  loadPixels();
  for (var x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < img.height; y++ ) {
      // Calculate the 1D location from a 2D grid
      var loc = (x + y*img.width)*4;

      // Get the R,G,B values from image
      var r = img.pixels[loc];
      var g = img.pixels[loc+1];
      var b = img.pixels[loc+2];

      // get mouse input on adjustment variables
      var adjustBrightness = (mouseX/width)*4;
      var adjustRed = (mouseY/height)*4;
      r *= adjustBrightness;
      g *= adjustBrightness; 
      b *= adjustBrightness;

      r *= adjustRed;
      // Constrain RGB to make sure they are within 0-255 color range
      r = constrain(r, 0, 255);
      g = constrain(g, 0, 255);
      b = constrain(b, 0, 255);

      // write back out pixel values
      pixels[loc] = r; //red
      pixels[loc+1] = g; //green
      pixels[loc+2] = b; //blue
      pixels[loc+3] = 255; //alpha
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

It runs much slower that the prossessing.js version. I'm not sure if that's because of an underlying difference or just inefficient coding!

Comment: Were you actually running the original code as JavaScript? Or were you just running it as Java from the Processing editor?

Comment: Yes, I compared the .pde run with processing.js and the p5.js script on the same apache2.4 server.  The processing code runs much faster (probably twice the update rate)

Answer (score 0):

These lines don't make sense:

```
r = red (img.pixels[loc]);
g = green (img.pixels[loc]);
b = blue (img.pixels[loc]);
```

The `pixels` array holds each color in a separate index. It should look more like this:

```
var r = img.pixels[loc];
var g = img.pixels[loc+1];
var b = img.pixels[loc+2];
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image).

Even after you fix that, you'll still have other problems. For example, when are you ever declaring your `c` variable?

If you still can't get it working, feel free to post the image you're using in a new question along with your updated code, and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: that got things on the right track, I will answer below with the working script.